# Why don't these normal forces, derived from different equations, equal

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces

Consider the following diagram.

[image: Diagram]

If I solve for the normal force obtained from the equation $F_{n}\cos\theta = mg$ and set it equal to $mg\cos\theta$ it shows it is not equal. Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relationship between $F_n$ and $mg$ depends on what constraints there are on the object’s motion (if any).

If the object is sliding down a plane at angle $\theta$ to the horizontal then it is in equilibrium in a direction perpendicular to the plane, which is the direction of $F_n$. So the net force parallel to $F_n$ must be zero and we have

$F_n = mg\cos \theta$

On the other hand, if we are told the object is moving horizontally then it is in equilibrium in the vertical direction. So the net vertical force on the object is zero and we have

$mg= F_n\cos \theta$

If the motion of the object is not constrained at all then there is no relationship between $F_n$ and $mg$.

Comment: say the inclined plane was moving  at an acceleration that prevented you from sliding down. Why would you use Fn cos 30 = mg rather than Fn= mgcos30

Comment: @JaysonMeribe If you know that the object is moving horizontally (i.e. not sliding up or down the plane) then the net vertical force on it must be zero, so $mg - F_n \cos \theta=0$ (assuming that $F_n$ and its weight $mg$ are the only forces acting on the object).

Comment: So you are saying Fn cosθ is equal to only the vertical component and doesn't account for the horizontal component of Fn on the inclined plane.

Comment: @JaysonMeribe Yes. $F_n \cos \theta$ is the vertical component of $\vec {F_n}$.

Answer (score 0):

$|mg| \ne |F_n\cos(\theta)|$ for $|\cos(\theta)| \ne 1$